# How to extract value from this CSS

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I actually want to extract the selected amount in jquery but struggling as the one string within CSS class( highlighted in yellow in image) changes for every product. So for some visitors to this page who have iphone 7 selected class name could be

> button button--select ng-tns-**c43**-1

and for other who are browsing with different product class name can be

> button button--select ng-tns-**c26**-1

[image: Please see this image with console screenshot]

Comment: Is it possible you can amend the HTML? It would be much better practice to store the required value in it's own `data` attribute instead of hacking around a `class` attribute string. As the saying goes, 'You have a problem; you want to edit a string. Someone suggests Regex. Now you have two problems'.

Comment: Looks like angular generated, which means you can apply some sort of active class on it during the generation then change that class instead, but without more information, not sure whether we can help.

Comment: @NelsonYeung - Hi Nelson - this is correct. It is an angular webiste. I was just wondering if any regex matching possible?  . Not an expert but this is what I was using - but it doesnt work ofcouse  jQuery("span.button.button--select [class*="ng-tns-"].is-selected").text();

Comment: @teluram If you have the angular code, can't you just add your own class to those buttons? It's better to do things normally than to hack around.

Comment: @NelsonYeung - I am unfortuately not the delevloper of this and cant add a class. I am a web analyst wo is just trying to extract the value. We can ask our dev team to make the change but unfortunately we are going live in 2 hours so was looking for a quick solution if possible

Comment: @NelsonYeung I am actually just a web analyst who is doing sone tagging work. The site is going live in next couple of hours and we dont have a dev resource for this so was looking for a quick hack currently and maybe our develops will fix it next week.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to extract all the classes for the whole DOM, then search through them and find the class that starts with `ng-tns-`.

```js
var values = [];
var allClasses = [];
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i += 1) {
  var classes = allElements[i].className.split(/\s+/);

  for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    var cls = classes[j];

    if (cls && allClasses.indexOf(cls) === -1) {
      allClasses.push(cls);

      if (cls.startsWith('ng-tns-')) {
        var ngTns = document.getElementsByClassName(cls);

        for (var k = 0; k < ngTns.length; k += 1) {
          if (ngTns[k].hasAttribute('is-selected')) {
            values.push(ngTns[k].innerText);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(values);
```

```html
<div class="button--select">
  <span class="ng-tns-c43-1">500</span>
  <span class="ng-tns-c43-1" is-selected>200</span>
  <span class="ng-tns-c43-1">100</span>
</div>
```